# How to show ipad library videos in CustomTableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

i wanna get all videos list from ipad video library and show in table view controller and then play inside the app. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

[This Developer.apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html) explains how to use an **image picker controller** and delegate for browsing and choosing saved pictures and movies. If the standard media browsing UI does not suit your needs, you can create a fully custom solution with UIKit and the Assets Library framework

**Media types** To specify whether the image picker controller displays saved movies, still images, or both, set the mediaTypes property to an array containing identifiers for the desired types. The valid values for elements of the array are kUTTypeImage and kUTTypeMovie.

**Presenting the media browser interface full screen on iPhone or iPod touch**

```
 -(BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller

               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,

                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {



    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:

                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)

            || (delegate == nil)

            || (controller == nil))

        return NO;



    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;



    // Displays saved pictures and movies, if both are available, from the

    // Camera Roll album.

     mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];



    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for

    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.

    mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;



    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;



    [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];

    return YES;

}

- (IBAction) showSavedMediaBrowser {

    [self startMediaBrowserFromViewController: self

                                    usingDelegate: self];

}
```

**Delegate method for picked media**

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker

            didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
}
```

Comment: nop i want to list the videos in my app. Just like a playlist

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can get all video's asset urls using the following code:

```
NSMutableArray* assetURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
    if(result != nil)
    {
        if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
        {
            [assetURLs addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

            NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
            NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]; 

            [library assetForURL:url
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
             {
                      // do stuff here
             }
             failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"test:Fail"); } ]; 
        } 
    }
};
```

You can use the asset url to get that video.
After that create the thumbnail of the video and display it in the tableView.
Also you can play the video using the asset url:

Asset url will look like: `assets-library://asset/asset.m4v?id=100&ext=m4v`

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"assets-library://asset/asset.m4v?id=100&ext=m4v";
NSURL *movieURL= [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
```

For more refer:

1. [AssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: but it sows the videos from "Photo Library" not from "Video app" in which movies or songs etc contain that we sync using itunes

Comment: @Hamdullahshah: which is not possible. Please ask question with detailed descriptions to avoid such misunderstanding :)